# What questions can be put into a survey to prevent low-quality responses?

Tags: research-process, experiment-design, survey-research

I'm designing a survey and I heard that there's a technique that sets up some questions in the middle of the survey to see if people are actually reading these questions.

Could anyone provide me the name of these kinds of studies, and examples of what kind of questions could be set up to prevent people from just submitting questionnaires without reading.

Comment: I think it is called mis-lingaurd or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

I know it under the term attention check questions. There are many methods, depending on if you're doing the survey online, want to/can use visual ones etc. I think this article might give a good overview, it gives examples and critiques them https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0272696317300402?casa_token=yZkLxSP9zGMAAAAA:gziLCRo_Feod6eXaoF7MwpAMiPjadDVvqRq4jgeqL4ed92qiMn7pJtm-_OogTEcB2YJKheEppdM